# Issues with running Joomla 3.8 and Civi

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I am not looking to be first on this - just wanted to see if anyone is running J3.8 and current release of Civi.

Comment: I upgraded to Joomla 3.8 last week and have been having the same cron error ever since. I tried the tweaks mentioned here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203 But those don't solve the issue. It would be great if there could be a definitive fix. Every time I either update Joomla or CiviCRM, something breaks with CiviCRM. Without fail. Is there an official fix for this yet? Five days without a running cron is a big hassle.

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. Consider rephrasing to something that solicits definitive answers, and where members of the community can vote for a "best" answer.

Answer (score 6):

The fix to the file CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php suggested in the link 
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11062/files?diff=unified
made the cron jobs run again for CiviCRM 4.7.25 and Joomla 3.8.1.

Comment: I installed the patch linked to above on Oct 6th, and have not since a problem with the CRON since.

Comment: Note that this fix won't solve all uses of Joomla cron for some CiviCRM installs.  The patch on https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20904 is also necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I took the plunge and upgraded Joomla to 3.8.0 today. I am seeing two problems with it and CiviCRM 4.7.24:

- cron jobs are not running
- In the backend, the Administer > Directories page is broken (only loads partially). There are 3 instances of "ReferenceError: CRM is not defined" appearing in Firebug console.

I have not looked into these any further yet. Cron jobs were definitely working prior to the Joomla upgrade but I don't know if the Directories page was already broken.

UPDATE: I've posted on [CRM-21203](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203) some changes to CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php that get cron jobs working (doesn't fix the Directories page). Joomla 3.8.0 has changed the location of some files in libraries/

Joomla 3.8.0 is a required security update for all previous versions.

Comment: I have raised a bug report:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203

Comment: Do you also have JoomSEF installed?

Comment: Thanks for confirming and creating the Jira issue. No I'm not using JoomSEF. I noticed that in Joomla 3.7, the class JObject is defined in libraries/joomla/object/object.php. In Joomla 3.8.0 object.php is not present and JObject is not defined anywhere else.

Comment: Actually I can see now that JObject is now supposed to be an alias for CMSObject so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I suspect that the JObject error may be just be a symptom. It could be that something in CiviCRM doesn't take account of the new routing regime in Joomla 3.8.
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:New_Routing_System
This could also explain the Directories page mess-up.

Comment: I submitted issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21209 about the Directories problem.

As a workaround hack, you can create folder "version" under /libraries/cms/, and create an empty file "version.php" in the new folder. Not pretty, but it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry. I see you already submitted  issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21208

Comment: I posted on the Joomla forum about the CRON issue, https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=3493718#p3493718, and got this reply:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- > 
This is no surprise. The router is completely rewritten in 3.8.0.
You have to contact the developer of the script.
<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Again, it appears that no one in the CiviCRM group is taking any notice of those of us using Joomla.

Comment: I think there are those using joomla who help maintain Civi - 3.8 was a pretty new release and destined to break some things - this has been a great post and highlighted the need to add some tweaks to the next Civi release. Thank you all for your comments

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to create a local WAMP site for Joomla betas, and then install CiviCRM to see what breaks in future

Comment: FWIW ... I tried the suggested patch in CRM-21203, and my CRON is still not running.   The fix for the JROUTER messages worked, but the CRON is still not running.

Answer (score 1):

I have a post-3.8 upgrade issue: I don't think it's related to the issue above but sharing in answer to the OP: [Joomla 3.8 & CiviCRM 4.7.x - front-end error 500 when logged in](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/joomla-3-8-civicrm-4-7-x-front-end-error-500-when-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not fixed in 4.7.27, appears to be slated for 4.7.28.  Manually applying the fix in Joomla.php file here seems to have resolved it https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11062